# Testing xml ignored in dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have this dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:14-jdk-hotspot

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.3
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=c35a1803a6e70a126e80b2b3ae33eed961f83ed74d18fcd16909b2d44d7dada3203f1ffe726c17ef8dcca2dcaa9fca676987befeadc9b9f759967a8cb77181c0
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y git \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
 && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
&& echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
&& tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
&& rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
&& ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY . app/.

WORKDIR "/app"

CMD ["mvn", "clean", "test"]
```

And I have set the XML `thread-count` to 10 and pom file can read it.

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I run in local `mvn clean test` the suite launches 10 tests at the same time and respects the tests in the xml, but when I run them in docker, the xml file is ignored.

Any ideas why the ${suiteXmlFile} is ignored? I also have tested add it as a variable to the docker.

Comment: What is the value of `${suiteXmlFile }` defined in your `<properties>` section ?

Comment: <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>

Comment: The container specifically cannot cause these problems, but your file/drive mapping can. We need to see how you're running the container and understand your directory/file structure.

Comment: btw: there is an official maven docker image with an openjdk11 base. Using it would simplify your dockerfile somewhat.

Comment: The problem was the docker file was built with the docker-compose, and was not refreshing the changes done in the docker file.

Comment: @Nonyck You mean `docker-compose build ...` didn't rebuild the image?